# Is it correct that master runs on a datanode?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, giraph

I'm using giraph-1.3 built with yarn profile. For starting I configured 1 namenode and 2 datanodes on a ec2 cluster.
My application properly works because I see expected output in logs (and in output directory). I launched giraph with "-w 2" argument because I have two datanodes.

In userlogs of datanode1 I found log of first worker.
in userlogs of datanode2 I found log of second worker and log of master too.

I expected to find log of master in the namenode i.e. I expected that master runs on namenode. Is it right?

Maybe I have to configure another datanode and then I will find master logs on this new datanode?

Comment: What file path are you seeing logs in? Are you sure that isn't the NodeManager, not the datanode?

Comment: I'm in the datanode. Thanks cricket_007

Comment: Your datanodes don't run YARN jobs unless you've also installed a NodeManager on them

Answer (score 0):

I understood that hadoop/giraph works creating containers on datanodes. Hadoop creates a container for application master, then giraph creates a container for the master. Furthermore giraph creates a number of container for workers corresponding to -w parameter.

Comment: Containers are created on NodeManagers, actually, which ideally is a service installed onto the datanodes

Answer (score 0):

YARN always creates an Application Master for every job.

You can start as many "workers" as you want, depending on your workload, but since you only have 2 datanodes, you can only have 2 NodeManagers for maximum parallelism

A NodeManager has a maximum memory space available to it, and the YARN containers for the tasks of a job get a subsection of that in order to do processing.